# Silverlight Bing error message in SSRS PowerPivot Report

Tags: silverlight, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, bing-maps, powerpivot

I have a current setup of SharePoint 2010 SP2 with PowerPivot Gallery and SSRS installed. While creating a Report from an Excel in the PowerPivot Gallery, I added a Map layout to plot cities. While this worked fine until yesterday, all of a sudden I receive Bing error: empty messages and one message saying:

```
Bing Error:[Arg_SecurityException]
Arguments:
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. 
See http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/DllResourceIDs/Default.aspx?Version=5.1.40416.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_SecurityException
```

Opening the MS link doesn't really help in solving the issue. Is there a way to debug this Silverlight message, like JavaScript console? Or do you have some possible suggestions on how to fix the Bing error in the Map encoding of the SSRS reports?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I found the root cause of the issue. Unsuspectingly, it was a Network issue. The proxy changed rules and the Network team blocked the URL to Bing Maps, thus making rendering of Bing Maps in SSRS impossible. After adding an exception to the Bing Maps URL in the proxy filter, the Maps are shown again.
This still doesn't answer my question regarding the debug of Silverlight errors, but it closes my case.